# Lookup transformation how to ignore trailing zeros in the start

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to compare two tables in different server. I'm using Lookup transformation is SSIS. In the tables two column are of different data types. In Lookup table it is varchar(255) and in other one it is int. I've tried casting the int ones to varchar(255) but the output of transform is wrong. Not sure what goes wrong. Any ideas?

```
Select CAST (CompanyNumber as Varchar(255)) is how I perform cast
```

Note:

I found out the issue. In source and destination there is difference in data like one is 070 and the other is 70. Any idea how to ignore the zeros in the start?

Comment: Wrong is when you converting int to varchar you get different result :) so maybe your casting code and examples should help

Comment: @Justin I've updated how i'm performing cast.

Comment: typo `CAST(CompanyNumber as Varchar(255))` and you get integers converted to what? code is good..

Comment: @Justin That's a typo here.I've updated it in the question but still my transform output is wrong!

Comment: @Justin I found out the issue. In source and destination there is difference in data like one is 070 and the other is 70. Any idea how to ignore the zeros in the start?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ignoring the leading zeros, embrace them:

```
RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 255) + CompanyNumber, 255)
```

Do this to both sides.   What it does is add 255 zeros before the string, and then get the right-most 255 characters.   Both resulting strings will be the same regardless of how many leading zeros they had to start.

Comment: Basically the company number column contains 3 digits. If it's two digits then only it comes with a 0 suffix. So i guess this won't work!

Comment: Why do you think that means this won't work?   If you are sure it will never be more than 3 digits, then you can change the 255's to 3's, but either way it should work.   Instead of guessing that it won't work, try it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a Data conversion transformation? You could use this to check that both returned table values are the same data type.

Comment: Yes I did converted using data conversion and that issue is resolved. Again having troubles dealing with data in the column. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could cast the varchar to int instead - that way the leading "0" would be removed and you could compare apples to apples.

Alternatively, you could use a transformation using the if conditional to test the first character (using LEFT) and then take the substring of the field excepting the "0".